# Magento and Wordpress integration on multiple languages

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to sketch the structure of my project, which is to use different Wordpress installations, each one with a subdomain representing each one a different country / language. The Wordpress is great to handle the pages and blog. I know that Magento lets you use a single Magento backend / stock for different sites.

What i want to do is to translate each wordpress on its language and subdomain, and then use the CART and ADD TO CART / CHECKOUT of Magento, but all the translated stores will use only one Magento stock / backend. The user login should be also integrated across WP / Magento.

For the Wordpress side I have found this:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/magento-wordpress-integration/

And this

http://codecanyon.net/item/single-signon-for-magento-and-wordpress/861453/comments

That should do the trick with the login, but will the cart / check out be able to be integrated too ?

And, can someone confirm this is even possible ? I really want to use Magento as backend of the same store but on different sites / languages. Maybe you can add the products by SKU, making them independent of the product name / language ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you already looked at the Fishpig single sign on Magento integration? They also have mutli store

Comment: Hi Chroma Funk and welcome To MageOverflow. I think this question is very broad and of course can everything be integrated, the question is always the costs. Not sure whether you will find here a satisfying answer.